# Cascaded Shadow Mapping lookup decision / gl_FragCoord.z

Tags: opengl, glsl

I've implemented Cascaded Shadow Mapping as in the nvidia SDK (http://developer.download.nvidia.com/SDK/10.5/Samples/cascaded_shadow_maps.zip). However my lookup just doesn't seem to work.

Here's a picture depicting my current state: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRAht.png

The problem is, I end up in the first split right away eventhough I'm far away from it. As you can see, the other splits aren't even considered.

I thought the reason for this might come from a different projection matrix the main engine is using. It's different from the one I supply to the algorithm but I also tried passing the same matrix to the shader and compute this way: gl_Position = matProj * gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex
That really didn't change a thing though. I still ended up with only one split.

Here are my shaders:

[vertex]

```
varying vec3 vecLight;
varying vec3 vecEye;
varying vec3 vecNormal;
varying vec4 vecPos;
varying vec4 fragCoord;
void main(void)
{
    vecPos = gl_Vertex;
    vecNormal = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal);
    vecLight = normalize(gl_LightSource[0].position.xyz);
    vecEye = normalize(-vecPos.xyz);

    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
    gl_Position = ftransform();
}
```

[fragment] (just the shadow  part)

```
vec4 getShadow()
{
    vec4 sm_coord_c = texmat_3*vecPos;
    float shadow = texture2D(smap_3, sm_coord_c.xy).x;
    float s = (shadow < sm_coord_c.z) ? 0.0 : 1.0;

    vec4 shadow_c = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0) * s;

    if(gl_FragCoord.z < vecFarbound.x)
    {
      vec4 sm_coord_c = texmat_0*vecPos;
      float shadow = texture2D(smap_0, sm_coord_c.xy).x;
      float s = (shadow < sm_coord_c.z) ? 0.0 : 1.0;

      shadow_c = vec4(0.7, 0.7, 1.0, 1.0) * s;
    }
    else if(gl_FragCoord.z < vecFarbound.y)
    {
      vec4 sm_coord_c = texmat_1*vecPos;
      float shadow = texture2D(smap_1, sm_coord_c.xy).x;
      float s = (shadow < sm_coord_c.z) ? 0.0 : 1.0;

      shadow_c = vec4(0.7, 1.0, 0.7, 1.0) * s;
    }
    else if(gl_FragCoord.z < vecFarbound.z)
    {
      vec4 sm_coord_c = texmat_2*vecPos;
      float shadow = texture2D(smap_2, sm_coord_c.xy).x;
      float s = (shadow < sm_coord_c.z) ? 0.0 : 1.0;

      shadow_c = vec4(1.0, 0.7, 0.7, 1.0) * s;
    }

    return shadow_c;
}
```

So for some reason, gl_FragCoord.z is smaller than vecFarbound.x no matter where in the scene I'm at. (Also notice the shadowed area to the far left, this one increases the higher I move the camera and soon takes over all the scene..)

I've checked the vecFarbound values and they're similar to the ones in nvidia's code so I assume I calculated them right.

Is there a way to check gl_FragCoord.z's value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my old csm implementation I simply used distance in camera space

```
float tempDist = 0.0;
tempDist = dot(EyePos.xyz, EyePos.xyz);
if (tempDist < split.x) ...
else if (tempDist < split.y) ...
...
```

Thsi solution was a bit simplier for me to understand and I got better control over the splits. When you use Z value (in clip space) there might be some problems that comes from z value being not-linear.

I suggest doing split tests in viewSpace, and then (if it works) use gl_FragCoord.z..

Comment: cool, I'll try this out! Thanks a lot, I'm really just struggeling with this part. I'll report back soon.

Comment: May I ask how you computed the split vector then? Right now I'm basing it on the z-Values of each split and the projection matrix. Doesn't seem to work for me with your proposal.

Comment: I based on http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch10.html where the splits are given in viewSpace and set using proposed equations.... look at "The Practical Split Scheme" in this link.

Comment: Sorry, haven't had time to try it until now.
I'm calculating those splits the very same way, for my current settings I have zNear starting at 1.0f and zFar going to 100.0f
This produces 3 split values: 12.XXf, 33.XXf and 100.0f
I send those to the shader and compare it against the eye distance (like you posted above) with this result: http://i.imgur.com/mypTA.png

Where blue is for <split.x, green for <split.y and red for <split.z

That doesn't map with my frustum at all as you can see here: http://i.imgur.com/wqDaJ.png
Im not quite sure what I'm missing here. Any idea?

Comment: Ahh I have to square the splits aswell dont I?

Comment: yes, yes... I compare SQUAREd distances of course... sorry that I did not pointed it out.